# Changing text in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I'm trying to change the text of a paragraph and everything that I can see in my code should work but it's not changing the text?

I've looked at multiple posts on stackoverflow already and I've implemented what they say but my paragraph is still not changing. I'm trying to change the paragraph based on what the user inputs in a form text box. Am I missing something?

```js
function ticketPrice() {

  var age = document.getElementById("age");
  var newAge = parseInt(age);

  if (newAge <= 5) {
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "Free";
  } else if (newAge >= 6 && newAge <= 17) {
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "Half Price";
  } else if (newAge >= 18 && newAge <= 55) {
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "Full Price";
  } else if (newAge >= 55) {
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "$2 off";
  } else
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "ERROR"
}
```

```html
<p>Please enter your age to find the price of your movie ticket.</p>
<form id="form1" action="" method="POST">
  Please enter your age:<br>
  <input type="text" name="age" value=""><br><br>
  <p id="price">Hello</p>
  <input type="button" onclick="ticketPrice()" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: A better event than the submit click is the form submit. Return false at the end to not submit the form or use event.preventDefault() to stop submission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're successfully updating the element, but then the form submission occurs (because the button is `type="submit"`), which reloads the page from the server, and so the old text shows up again.

If you don't want the form to submit, change the type to `button`.

Two other problems with the code:

1. You're looking up the `age` element by `id`, but it doesn't have an `id`, it just has a `name`. Add `id="age"` to it.
2. You're using the element itself when parsing to integer; you want to use its *value* (add `.value`).

So (see comments):

```js
function ticketPrice() {

  // *** .value on the next line
  var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
  var newAge = parseInt(age);

  if (newAge <= 5) {
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "Free";
  } else if (newAge >= 6 && newAge <= 17) {
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "Half Price";
  } else if (newAge >= 18 && newAge <= 55) {
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "Full Price";
  } else if (newAge >= 55) {
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "$2 off";
  } else
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "ERROR"
}
```

```html
<p>Please enter your age to find the price of your movie ticket.</p>
<form id="form1" action="" method="POST">
  Please enter your age:<br>
  <!-- *** id="age" *** -->
  <input type="text" name="age" id="age" value=""><br><br>
  <p id="price">Hello</p>
  <!-- *** type=button *** -->
  <input type="button" onclick="ticketPrice()" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
    <input type="submit" onclick="ticketPrice()" value="submit">
```

to

```
    <input type="button" onclick="ticketPrice()" value="submit">
```

it is not working because every time you click submit the form is submited.

to prevent submission change the input type to button

Answer (score 0):

A better event than the submit click is the form submit. Return false at the end to not submit the form or use event.preventDefault() to stop submission

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/mkgb57mu/)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
    var age = parseInt(document.getElementById("age").value), text = "ERROR";
    console.log(age)
    if (age <= 5) text = "Free";
    else if (age >= 6 && age <= 17)  text = "Half Price";
    else if (age >= 18 && age <= 55) text = "Full Price";
    else if (age >= 55) text= "$2 off";
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = text;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Please enter your age to find the price of your movie ticket.</p>
<form id="form1" action="" method="POST">
  Please enter your age:<br>
  <!-- *** id="age" *** -->
  <input type="text" name="age" id="age" value="" /><br><br>
  <p id="price">Hello</p>
  <!-- *** type=button *** -->
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```